# detect enter key js - not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<a class="link_standard" id="login">Login</a> 

<div id="loginpop">
  <input type="text" id="emaillogin" class="form-control input-sm" />                  
  <input type="password" id="pwdlogin" class="form-control input-sm" />
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#loginpop').hide();
  $('#login').popover({
    html: true, 
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: function(){
      return $('#loginpop').html();
    }
  });
  $('#login').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
    $('#pwdlogin').keydown(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
        alert('test enter');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

What i want is:

After I enter the password, if i hit the enter key, it should alert('test enter'), but it is not working. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved, the geek was:

```
$('#login').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
          $('#pwdlogin').keydown(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
              alert('test enter');
            }
          });
       });
```

not `show` but `shown`

Answer (score 1):

`$('#pwdlogin').keydown` should be directly in `$(function(){` block.

Comment: doesnot work, it was my first attempt.. the popup is hidden, thats why the event handler should be attached after ``.html();``

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
 $('#loginpop').hide();
 $('#login').popover({
     html: true, 
     placement: 'bottom',
     content: function(){
        return $('#loginpop').html();
     }
 });

    $('#pwdlogin').keydown(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
       alert('test enter');
      }
    });

});
```